# Help on Schematic for ATMEGA64 and FT232RL

Tags: schematics

I am relatively new to electronics and was trying to make a PCB with Atmega64 and FT232RL, similar to an Arduino. Pictures of my schematic are attached below. The wires in the top right of the FT232RL picture and the wires in the top left of the Atmega64 picture are connected (you can see the resistor and capacitor in both pictures). The power supply circuit is not included, but for your reference, it is exactly the same as the traditional Arduino power supply circuit. None of the I/O pins on the Atmega64 have been connected to anything yet- only the basic circuits for the crystal oscillator, overall microcontroller power, the UART bridge, and the reset button are completed. Mainly, I was wondering if my reset button circuit, connecting the FT232RL and Atmega64 was correct. If any other errors catch your eyes, please let me know.

Thanks so much for the help in advance[image: enter imagenter image description heree description here]

[image]

Comment: Please use the circuit tool and edit your question. The images are not readable it would be better if you drew a simplified diagram (draw only the pins that are used) with the tool

Comment: Did you have a specific question?  Broad design reviews are not exactly encouraged.  Probably your best reference would be the Arduino Duemilanove schematic; if you've made intentional changes from that apart from the small diferences of a different ATmega) which you wish to ask about, please use the "edit" button to state those as specific questions.

Comment: Your schematics will be readable with little effort if you take a picture with OfficeLens or a similar free app. It compensates the perspective distortion and uneven lightning. And it let's you rotate the images to a readable orientation.